# Android firebase invalid token in path when using string, but perfect result when using literal string

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I run the following code I get an error

```
uuid = result.getContents();
uuidBox.setText("UUID: " + uuid);

//Get StudentID
mDatabase.child("users").child(uuid).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
            System.out.println("THE UUID IS " + uuid);
        } else {
            String studentID = String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue());
            studentBox.setText(studentID);
        }
    }
});
```

The error is as follows:

```
2022-06-20 16:32:37.238 6195-6195/com.example.couponsapp E/firebase: Error getting data java.lang.Exception: Invalid token in path 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.lambda$get$0$com-google-firebase-database-connection-PersistentConnectionImpl(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:425) 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onResponse(Unknown Source:6) 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$6.onResponse(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:1292) 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.onDataMessage(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:496) 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onDataMessage(Connection.java:167) 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection.onMessage(Connection.java:131) 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.appendFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:259) 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame(WebsocketConnection.java:306) 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection.access$500(WebsocketConnection.java:34) 
at com.google.firebase.database.connection.WebsocketConnection$WSClientTubesock$2.run(WebsocketConnection.java:86) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

JSON:

```
  "users": {
    "-N5-HbHttT0yUMO7ebxD": {
      "studentBal": 4000,
      "studentID": "P-2329",
      "studentName": "Hello World"
    },
    "HaMeP1-273299386": {
      "studentBal": 2800,
      "studentID": "P-1329",
      "studentName": "Ha Me"
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this exact same code by directly inputting the ID into the .child(), it works perfectly fine, but when I add the string, it breaks down and gives the error. I have verified that the string is indeed the same value by printing it in the log, so it is not a problem of the string being defined incorrectly or something. The string, UUID is a standard firebase generated UUID with the value of:

> -N5-HbHttT0yUMO7ebxD

I am literally losing my mind please help.

Comment: Show in the code where and how you use a string literal, and a log statement of the string variable you try to use confirming that it is in fact the same string. (e.g. `System.out.println("UUID = '" + uuid + "'");` If you added a log statement confirming it, show where it is in the code (edit the question) and show what output it gives. Strings are not magic, if the behavior is different the string is different.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Tyler asked for, and please also respond with @.